# How to add a calculated column of certain rows in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to add a calculated column (persisted) that is the total rows for the same group of categories such as sales order below. How would you do this in SQL Server?

```
  SalesOrder    Amount    Total(calculated)
    100            10      25
    100            15      25
    101            20      45
    101            25      45
    102            30      65
    102            35      65
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best mechanism to use for storing pre-calculated aggregates that are automatically maintained would be an indexed view, it is not possible via a persisted computed column (you could use a scalar UDF in a computed column to calculate the result but this can't be persisted and such computed columns are generally bad for performance both as they force RBAR evaluation and as they block parallelism).

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.AggregatedSales
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT SalesOrder,
       SUM(Amount) AS Total
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY SalesOrder

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UIX ON dbo.AggregatedSales(SalesOrder)
```

Then the aggregates will be pre calculated and stored in the view. Your queries will need to join on the view. You may need to use the `NOEXPAND` hint to be sure that the pre calculated aggregates are in fact used and they aren't recalculated at runtime.

Comment: Great, thanks! The speed of stackexchange is amazing.

Comment: @el_kraken, If this answer is useful to you, accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL server 2012

```
CREATE TABLE #t (saleOrder int , amount int)

    INSERT INTO #t VALUES 
    (100,10)
    ,(100,15)
    ,(101,20)
    ,(101,25)
    ,(102,30)
    ,(102,35)

        SELECT *
            ,SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY saleorder)  as [total]
        FROM #t
```

Result :

```
saleOrder | amount | total
==========================
    100   |   10   |  25
    100   |   15   |  25
    101   |   20   |  45
    101   |   25   |  45
    102   |   30   |  65
    102   |   35   |  65
```

Comment: This actually works in 2005+ if they decide not to bother with the pre calculation.